# odoo payments bad query null value since upgrade to oddo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

with Odoo 10 CE we changed the way of addinb bank-accounts within partners/customers to an inline version:

Original Code:

```
        <group string="Payments" name="banks">
                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <div>
                            <button type="action" class="btn-link"
                                name="%(base.action_res_partner_bank_account_form)d"
                                context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id, 'default_partner_id': active_id}">
                                <field string="Bank account(s)" name="bank_account_count" widget="statinfo"/>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </group>
```

Customized Version:

```
            <group>
                        <group string="Payments">
                            <field name="bank_ids" nolabel="1"
                                context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id, 'default_partner_id': active_id}">
                                <tree>
                                    <field name="acc_number" string="IBAN" />
                                    <field name="bank_bic" string="BIC" />
                                    <field name="bank_name" />
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                        </group>
                    </group>
```

This worked fine in odoo10

But in odoo 11 after adding a new bank account within editview of customer the name of the bank will not be visible in the tree-view (only account-number is visible) and when trying to save the customer the following error is in odoo-log:

ERROR odoonew odoo.sql_db: bad query: b'UPDATE "res_bank" SET "name"=NULL,"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone \'UTC\') WHERE id IN (2)'

any ideas whats different in odoo11 here?

Comment: Have you extended anything else? seems that you have changed somehow the form view for `res.partner.bank` to add the bank_name or something that it's triggering the update of the field `name` in an existing res.bank record

Comment: the only additional change was regarding the change of the acc_number label. no more other changes regarding res.partner.bank.